# How to setup tests for an IntelliJ IDEA Python-extending plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been working on an IntelliJ IDEA plugin, and it works, as far as it is designed.
It is a plugin designed for supporting a particular Python library, and it plugs into extension points of the IntelliJ/PyCharm Python support.

I added the `python` jar to the IntelliJ SDK classpath, and I declared it as a dependency for my plugin. It has worked well enough for compiling and running the plugin as intended, as a plugin in the IDE.

I have not been able to run unit tests for this plugin - that is, I have written some tests (with code inspired by [`PyTestCase`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/testSrc/com/jetbrains/python/fixtures/PyTestCase.java)), but they always fail when `PythonSdkType.getInstance()` is called, in the [`SdkType.findInstance(Class<?>)`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/306d705e1829bd3c74afc2489bfb7ed59d686b84/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/projectRoots/SdkType.java#L211-L221) method - the [`assert false` line](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/306d705e1829bd3c74afc2489bfb7ed59d686b84/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/projectRoots/SdkType.java#L219) is reached.

I think that there must be some missing setup to initialize the Python SDK, but I do not know what - I am using a regular JUnit run configuration.